# How can I make this section full height of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I am hoping this can be done by only setting the height for the parent container and leaving the rectangles as they are relative to the parent container. I don't mean modifying the size of the individual rectangle components, I mean making the entire container fit screen height.
Thanks --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'''

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.screen a {
  display: contents;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container-center-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-center-horizontal > * {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ray106 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 740px;
  width: 360px;
}

.ray106 .component-1-1 {
  background-color: #463af2;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  height: 740px;
}

.ray106 .rectangle-2 {
  background-color: #f61a1a;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  height: 677px;
  left: 33px;
  position: relative;
  top: 31px;
  width: 292px;
}
</style>
</head>
   <body style="margin: 0; background: #ffffff">
    <input type="hidden" id="anPageName" name="page" value="ray106" />
    <div class="container-center-horizontal">
      <div class="ray106 screen">
        <div class="component-1-1">
          <div class="rectangle-2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

'''

Comment: he also added...

Comment: @AmanSharma my bad mouse prob

Answer (score 0):

Add `.container-center-horizontal {height: 100vh}`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

> this section

Not sure which element you mean -

Typically, the CSS to set an element to the viewport height is

```css
height: 100vh;
```

Meaning '**100**% of the **v**iewport **h**eight'.

Comment: I would like to make the whole thing fit screen height.  '100% of the viewport height'.

Comment: Not sure which element you mean - what is "the whole thing". Just apply it to the element you mean. So if you mean the `<div class="container-center-horizontal">`, then `.container-center-horizontal { height: 100vh; }`

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with the appropriate terms. The modifications you made produce the required output, thank you. But the method has me also modifying the shape of ray106 .rectangle-2. I would like to avoid this because if I have large number of rectangles per page it will mean tweaking the heights of all of them for every page. I was looking for a way to just scale up the whole page (or container) to fit any screen.  I had already tried .container-center-horizontal { height: 100vh; } before asking for help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set `height:100vh` for the parent container and set `height: 100%` for the purple rectangle. Set height in `%` for the red rectangle and set it in center by setting `top:50%`, `left:50%`, `transform:translate(-50%,-50%)`. By this way you can achieve responsive box

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
  *{box-sizing: border-box;}
.screen a {
  display: contents;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container-center-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container-center-horizontal > * {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ray106 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 360px;
}

.ray106 .component-1-1 {
  background-color: #463af2;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  height: 100%;
}

.ray106 .rectangle-2 {
  background-color: #f61a1a;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  height: 92%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: relative;
  width: 292px;
}
</style>
</head>
   <body style="margin: 0; background: #ffffff">
    <input type="hidden" id="anPageName" name="page" value="ray106" />
    <div class="container-center-horizontal">
      <div class="ray106 screen">
        <div class="component-1-1">
          <div class="rectangle-2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was hoping this can be done by only setting the height for the parent container and leaving the rectangles as they are relative to the parent container.

Comment: Yes of course or you could set the height for the purple rectangle both works